# Saving Data on GAE: logging vs. datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a google app engine app that has to deal with a lot of data collecting. The data I gather is around millions of records per day. As I see it, there are two simple approaches to dealing with this in order to be able to analyze the data:

  1. use logger API to generate app engine logs, and then try to load these up to a big query (or more simply export to CSV and do the analysis with excel).

  2. saving the data in the app engine datastore (ndb), and then download that data later / try to load that up to big query.

Is there any preferable method of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery has a new [Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), which they claim was designed for high-volume real-time data collection.

Advice from practice: we are currently logging 20M+ multi-event records a day via a method 1. as described above. It works pretty well, except when the batch uploader is not called (normally every 5min), then we need to detect this and re-run the importer. 
Also, we are currently in process of migrating to new Streaming API, but is not yet in production so I can't say how reliable it is.

Comment: I think I'm going to give Steaming API a shot. Thanks for sharing from your personal experience, helps a lot.